# Terminology for two trefoil knots linked together

Tags: terminology, knot-theory

Is there a term describe the link formed by two trefoil knots (or any prime knots, I suppose) [linked together like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljie6.png)?

Also, does that particular link correspond to a prime link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link formed by linking together the two trefoils (or any pair of nontrivial prime knots) is not prime.  There is a sphere intersecting the link in exactly two points such that each side of the sphere is a non-trivial tangle:

[image: A decomposition sphere for linked nontrivial prime knots]

Note that there are two ways to link two knots together:

[image: Linking two knots together]

These might be the same, but not in general.  The case in which they *are* the same is when $K_1$ or $K_2$ is an invertible knot (an oriented knot $K$ is *invertible* if it is isotopic to $K$ with reversed orientation -- many small knots are invertible, like the trefoil).

As for what to call it, I might call it a *plumbing* of a split link with a Hopf link.  Given the split link formed by $K_1$ and $K_2$,

[image: Split link of K1 and K2]

then by plumbing in a Hopf link in the region between the two components, as portrayed by this diagram, the result is either of the two ways of linking the two knots together.

Another thing I might call it is a satellite operation, where $K_1$ and $K_2$ are patterns inserted into a Hopf link companion.  This point of view comes from thinking of the linked knots as being the connect sum of $K_1$, $K_2$, and a Hopf link.  It's true that connect sums are not well-defined for links, but it becomes well-defined if you say *where* the connect sums occur.  The $K_1$ and $K_2$ knots are connect-summed into different components of the Hopf link.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!